# blueimp jquery file upload fails on images over 1mb

Tags: jquery, image-uploading, blueimp

I don't really know any where else to look or ask, on the support section in GitHub it suggested to start a question here. Is anyone here familiar enough with the framework to have a clue where to start?

Hoping I don't have to dive in blind. Thanks. If you really want to see a version of it you would have to sign up at http://merkd.com/signup then go to http://merkd.com/settings/icon to test it. I've tested it with a 978kb image and it works fine but I tried a 1.8mb, 2.2mb, and 3.7mb image and none of them work. The progress bar goes slow for a tiny bit, then it just speeds up as if it were a 50kb file.

I hope this is an easy fix. I was hoping to save time and use an already existing client-end upload framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the documentation, setting max file size that can be uploaded?

Also try checking the [FAQ's](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), found out that it could be the browser you are testing on

Comment: Your FAQ's link does not work, just returns me to this page. Also, yes, I have checked the documentation and even added a maxfilesize attribute of 1gb or so just to be sure that isn't the issue. Also tried a regular file upload form with a 3mb file and it works fine. Could be my browser, but I'm using Chrome, so I'll have to look into that.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed it now